# How to retry an external service when a call to an internal service fails using spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm implementing a service that mocks another service available on the web.
I'm trying to configure the spring cloud gateway to reroute requests to the public service when a call to my implementation fails.

I tried using the Hystrix filter the following way:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: foo
        uri: http://my-internal-service/
        filters:
        - name: Hystrix
          args:
            name: fallbackcmd
            fallbackUri: https://the.public.service/
```

Unfortunately, like the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.0.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_hystrix_gatewayfilter_factory) says:

> Currently, only forward: schemed URIs are supported. If the fallback is called, the request will be forwarded to the controller matched by the URI.

Therefore, I can't use `fallbackUri: https://...`.

Is there any plan to support this feature soon?
Otherwise, what are my options for this particular use case?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a kind of hacky workaround that seems to work for my particular use case (i.e. a GET request):

1. Create my own fallback controller in the Gateway application
2. Configure the hystrix fallback to point to that controller
3. Use the WebClient to call my public service

This is what the end result looks like:

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - name: AddResponseHeader
        args:
          name: X-Data-Origin
          value: My internal service
      routes:
      - id: foo
        uri: http://my-internal-service/
        filters:
        - name: Hystrix
          args:
            name: local-service-fallback
            fallbackUri: forward:/fallback/foo
```

*FallbackController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/fallback")
public class FallbackController {

    private static final String fallbackUri = "https://the.public.service";

    WebClient webClient;

    public FallbackController() {
        webClient = WebClient.create(fallbackUri);
    }

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    Mono<MyResponse> foo(ServerWebExchange failedExchange) {
        failedExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().remove("X-Data-Origin");
        failedExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("X-Data-Origin", "The public service");

        // Now call the public service using the same GET request
        UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
            .uri(URI.create(fallbackUri))
            .path("/path/to/service")
            .queryParams(failedExchange.getRequest().getQueryParams())
            .build();

        return WebClient.create(uriComponents.toUriString())
                .get()
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
                .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess(clientResponse -> {
                // Copy the headers from the public service's response back to our exchange's response
                    failedExchange.getResponse().getHeaders()
                         .addAll(clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders());
                })
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    log.info("Data origin: {}", 
                             failedExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().get("X-Data-Origin"));
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class);
                });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to solve.

I added new route for fallback and it worked.

```
.route(p -> p .path("/fallback/foo").uri("https://example.com"))
```